# Excel formula to split an amount per year depending on expenditure days within a date range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, formula, excel-2007

I am in the process of building a formula to split a total cost (in column J) based on start and end expenditure periods that can vary from 2021 to 2031. Based on the days between the expenditure period dates (column M), I managed to work out to split the cost using the formulas below up to 2023 but it is not consistent and at times incorrect.

[image: Sample result]

In cell P5 I have the following formula. For year 2021, I seem to get the correct split result.
=IF($K5>AS5,0,$J5/$M5*(AS5-$K5))

In cell Q5, I have the following formula. For year 2022, I seem to get the correct spit as well
=MIN(IF(SUM($N5:P5)>=$J5,0,IF($L5>=AS5,$J5/$M5*(AS5-AR5),$J5/$M5*($L5-MAX(AR5,$K5)))),K5)

However, I don't get the right result in cell Q6 which has the same formula but different dates
=MIN(IF(SUM($N6:P6)>=$J6,0,IF($L6>=AS6,$J6/$M6*(AS6-AR6),$J6/$M6*($L6-MAX(AR6,$K6)))),K6)

Cell R6 shouldn't return any result because it is out of date range. This is where things get mixed up.

Note that from column AR to BC, it is all year end dates from 2020 to 2031 as shown below.

[image: Sample data]

Is there a better way to tackle this sort of formula as I seem to get dragged into a long and unreliable way of doing this.

Comment: Just use days. Below the header, place year end date (ROW 5). The formula shall be: "=IF($K6>P$5,IF(P$5-$K6>365,"",$J6-sum($O6:O6)),(P$5-$K6)/$M6*$J6-sum($O6:O6))" at new P6 cell. Later drag it... At Q6 you will get "=IF($K6>Q$5,IF(Q$5-$K6>365,"",$J6-sum($O6:P6)),(Q$5-$K6)/$M6*$J6-sum($O6:P6))", so you are getting the cost from the start since the end of the current year at that cell minus previous expenses and you get another condition for the last year. Before and after beginning and end you will get blank. I replied it without my computer, so maybe some slight arrange needed.

Comment: thank you @DavidGarcíaBodego. Your solution has a similar issue than mine, in that it doesn't seem to return a zero value when the entire amount has been spread accordingly. The answer below from JB-007 really answers it. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9gY5Wlcaey1ay8mIxHg?e=1nw4AN) single function(♣) that will create a series of pro-rata multipliers (of appropriate length) for any given start/end date:

***EDIT:** **see end of soln for extended version per OP comment to original soln...***

---

**SINGLE FUNCTION**

```
=J11*(LET(dates,EDATE(DATE(YEAR($K11),1,1),12*(SEQUENCE(1,YEAR($L11)-YEAR($K11)+2,1))),IF(dates<K11,K11,IF(dates<L11,dates,L11)))-LET(dates,EDATE(DATE(YEAR($K11)-1,1,1),12*(SEQUENCE(1,YEAR($L11)-YEAR($K11)+2,1))),IF(dates<K11,K11,IF(dates<L11,dates,L11))))/(L11-K11)
```

[image: Full function]

It may appear somewhat unwieldy in length, but it is far more robust (and concise) compared to the combination of steps/series you have created.  What's more, it returns the precise answer RE: pro-rata payments and is guarenteed to never over/under-run RE: total payment (by design).

---

**BREAK-DOWN**

Comprises 3 distinct parts (some of which are similar in pattern/formation):

**1] First part** - create a series (array) of years spanning start-end dates:

```
=LET(dates,EDATE(DATE(YEAR($K5)-1,1,1),12*(SEQUENCE(1,YEAR($L5)-YEAR($K5)+2,1))),IF(dates<K5,K5,IF(dates<L5,dates,L5)))
```

[image: First part - series of dates of appropriate length/span]

Thanks to the lovely *Spill* functionality the new Office 365 variant Excel boasts, you never have to worry about how many years are required -- so long as you have the space to the right of this workbook (would be unusual otherwise - assuming you start in column O and clear any content to the right of this, you'd need an end date beyond the year 2557 (26th century) to run out of columns! ☺

---

**2]  Second part** is merely a replica of the firs series, albeit shifted to the right 'once' (so starts with the 2nd element in the 1st series):

```
=LET(dates,EDATE(DATE(YEAR($K5),1,1),12*(SEQUENCE(1,YEAR($L5)-YEAR($K5)+2,1))),IF(dates<K5,K5,IF(dates<L5,dates,L5)))
```

[image: Second part - shifted dates]

---

**3] Third part** - you have the basic ingredients from parts 1 and 2 to complete the required task easily: simply deduct series 2 from 1 (giving days between successive dates in series 1 - i.e. days for each year between start and end dates), divide by total days (to yield pro-rata multipliers), and then multiply these by the total £amount and **voila** - you have your series!

```
=J5*(O6#-O5#)/(M5)
```

[image: Third part: pro-rata yearly multipliers x total (£) cost]

---

*♣ Caveat(s) - assuming you have Office 365 compatible version of Excel (which is quite common nowadays)*

---

---

### ***EDIT - EXTENDED VERSION**

Given above, the following *extends* this to align monetary results (1st table, o11:w21) within respective *calendar period* columns (spanning the entire period in question).

This soln:

1. Determines header row based upon the number of columns & corresponding calender periods (financial yrs commencing 1/1) as an array function (i.e. dynamic range)
2. Utilises a modified version of the eq. provided for *dates* arrage (refer: "First Part", original soln)

*Comment* - *same caveats as before - i.e. Office 365 etc.*

Screenshot(s)/[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9gY5Wlcaey1ay8mIxHg?e=4B2nDK) refers:

---

**DATES (HEADER) - Y10 (array)**

```
=LET(y_,MIN(K11:K21),x_,MAX(L11:L21),EDATE(DATE(YEAR(y_)-1,1,1),12*(SEQUENCE(1,YEAR(x_)-YEAR(y_)+2,1))))
```

[image: Header function: start of each financial period spanning entire base period]

*Comment* - *enter once within single cell Y10 - i.e. as an array function with Spill to right*

---

**ALIGNED/SHIFTED FINANCIALS - Y11:Y21 (each cell in col is an array)**

```
=IFERROR(IF(Y$10#<EDATE(K11,-12),"",IF(Y$10#>EDATE(L11,12),"",INDEX(O11#,1,MATCH(Y$10#,EDATE(DATE(YEAR($K11)-1,1,1),12*(SEQUENCE(1,YEAR($L11)-YEAR($K11)+2,1))),0)))),"")
```

[image: Aligned financial pro-rata data table]

*Comment* - *enter this as an array fn. (#SPILL! to the right) in each cell within column Y (can drag this function down Y11:Y21 as required)*

---

Comment: _ @JB-007: How does this fair with leap years etc. and if you had to modify to allow for working days (e.g. ~200 or 50 weeks per year how you modify it mate?)

Comment: @DukeNukem - RE: leap years: handles fine (taken into account via calculating days difference - fyi annoyingly Excel does not have a convenient 'daysdiff' feature like you might find in SQL/SAS code variants (or is it VBA - I forget but anyways I also digress ☺)  RE: working days - use something like networkdays(series 1, series 2, <bank hols>) for third step (with denominator being networkdays (start, end, <hols>) - that'll do the trick and modify the schedule accordingly (will still handle leap and ensure total amount reconciles as req.)

Comment: Haha - couldn't squeeze link into previous comment (silly Stackoverflow character limit :) https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/excel/functions/calculate-working-days-excel-between-two-dates/

Comment: @JB-007 that's such a great formula. I just find that if the start date isn't the same between rows, you can't drag it down. The formula has to be used from the column the start year starts , which is totally fine. (i.e. you can't start using it for your column titled 2020 if the start expenditure date starts in 2021 so left 2020 blank and started using it in 2021 and so on for all the cells). I couldn't have asked for a better formula, thanks for sharing your skills.

Comment: @Abigal - see edited soln (*bottom of original*) -- let me know if this is not what you were looking for, will go back to drawing board :), Br, JB

Comment: @JB-007 It is exactly that. the first answer was more than good enough now it is even beyond that. thanks a million. JB, I will have to play with it to allow minor changes I am making to the file but I see exactly what it does and how it all comes together.

Comment: Glad this helped - if you need someone to help explain functions/operation (should you be interested/curious I can break them down) - otherwise happy days! br, J

Comment: I am working on amending this formula to split the amount in column “J” based on the number of months per year equally regardless of the number of days in each month (rather than based on the number of days per year). Grateful for any suggestion